# Creating a MAPI Session in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, mapi

I need to send some eMails from an excel-sheet. I currently use Excel2010, but it should also work with 2013. I searched the net for a solution and found a function, which unfortunatly doesn't work for me.

```
Sub SendMail(Recepient As String, Address As String, Subject As String, Contents As String)
  Dim mapi_session As MSMAPI.MAPISession
  Dim mapi_messages As MSMAPI.MAPIMessages
  'Set mapi_session = New MSMAPI.MAPISession
  Set mapi_session = CreateObject("MAPI.Session")

  ...
```

At line `Set mapi_session = New MSMAPI.MAPISession` it throws an error, saying "Unable to create object by ActiveX component (I translated from german)". I did some more investigation and came across a thread that suggested to use CreateObject instead, but it still throws the same error.
I included the msmapi32.ocx beforehand.

I'm pretty new to VBA - any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: The problem is possibly that you're running a 64 bit office / windows and the `MSMAPI` doesn't support it. [**`THIS`**](http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/) could be a possible solution

Comment: Yep, I am running a 64bit Version. I'd like to avoid a registry hack because the excel-sheet will be used at more than one computer of my colleagues. So, if sending Mail with the MAPI doesn't work for 64bit systems - maybe there is an other way sending mail via Excel?

Comment: Can I create a function, that sends a mail to a number of people with a individual pdf attached for everyone? The idea, why to use excel was: A column for the mail-adresse and a column with the filename for each person. Then send a mail to each person with the corresponding file as an attachment. If there is an other solution than Excel and VBA, I'd be fine with that ...

Comment: Ok, seems to be easier to write a small C# program using System.Net.Mail than haggling around with this VBA stuff. Thanks for pointing the way!

Answer (score 2):

CDO 1.21 (that is what "`MAPI.Session`" is) is no longer being installed by Outlook. You can download it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3671, but keep in mind that it is no longer being developed or supported by Microsoft.

What do you do with CDO 1.21? You really need to change your code to use only the [Outlook Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866465.aspx). You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - it's [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects is (just like CDO 1.21) an in-proc MAPI wrapper and its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object is similar to `MAPI.Session` in CDO 1.21 (but has quite a few extra goodies).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Set mapi_session = CreateObject("MSMAPI.MAPISession")`.